# how to render loaded html text with classname inside vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I try to render some html text loaded in a json file.

the textstring holds an class="" css style

```
"example": word 1<br><span class=\"main-color\">word 2</span> word 3"
```

the vuejs part looks like this:

```
<p v-html="example">  </p>
```

the scoped css:

```
.main-color  {
  color: #ff00ff;
}
```

the html code looks as expected in debugger, but the text was not rendered! why?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `"` at the start of the variable

[This works](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdCBzZXR1cD5cbmltcG9ydCB7IHJlZiB9IGZyb20gJ3Z1ZSdcbmNvbnN0IGV4YW1wbGUgPSByZWYoXCJ3b3JkIDE8YnI+PHNwYW4gY2xhc3M9XFxcIm1haW4tY29sb3JcXFwiPndvcmQgMjwvc3Bhbj4gd29yZCAzXCIpXG48L3NjcmlwdD5cblxuPHRlbXBsYXRlPlxuPHAgdi1odG1sPVwiZXhhbXBsZVwiPiAgPC9wPlxuPC90ZW1wbGF0ZT5cblxuPHN0eWxlPlxuLm1haW4tY29sb3IgIHtcbiAgY29sb3I6ICNmZjAwZmY7XG59XG48L3N0eWxlPiIsImltcG9ydC1tYXAuanNvbiI6IntcbiAgXCJpbXBvcnRzXCI6IHt9XG59In0=)

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const example = ref("word 1<br><span class=\"main-color\">word 2</span> word 3")
</script>

<template>
<p v-html="example">  </p>
</template>

<style>
.main-color  {
  color: #ff00ff;
}
</style>
```